# 10/100 Mbit/s network enough to test ISP using speedtest-cli

Tags: home-networking, internet-speed, speedtest

**Questions**

- Using a device with a 10/100 Mbit/s Ethernet port can I still proof
  the speed of my 50 Mbit/s fibercable connection or do I need a Gbit/s
  connection? I so far assumed yes but a no from a ISP technician without details.
- How can I interpret speedtest-cli results (see data)?
- I also found out my network provider (aka ISP) offers only IPv6 links. I therefore use DS-lite for IPv4 tunneling. I now ask myself if this could also be a cause of my latency problems?
- How can I dig deeper finding the cause of my ping jumping?
- Are there better ways to debug speed problems?

**Background story**

I have a 50 Mbit/s fibercable connection and am quite unsatisfied with the service. In peak hours I "felt" the service was slow and webpages took longer to load.

To "proof" it I wrote [this](https://github.com/lony/speed_test) script in Python. It uses the speedtest-cli to make ping and up- and download tests against a server in Frankfurt, Dublin, NY and LA. It also uses nmap to verify how many "machines" are currently inside my network. This way I know if the drain could come from someone watching Netflix. I installed the script as cronjob running every hour on a Raspberry 3, with has only a 10/100 Mbit/s ethernet port.

**Example data**

```
| Datetime | Hosts | Ping | Upload | Bytes_sent | Download | Bytes_Recived |
| 2018-01-19T00:00:02 | 5 | 456,686 | 8859432,21 | 11329536 | 42387039,13 | 53647395 |
| 2018-01-19T01:00:02 | 6 | 55,487 | 9690568,263 | 12394496 | 48871132,88 | 61671954 |
| 2018-01-19T02:00:02 | 4 | 46,576 | 9553857,186 | 12460032 | 39940398,74 | 50407954 |
| 2018-01-19T03:00:02 | 5 | 69,093 | 9729516,601 | 12476416 | 47199896,03 | 59754036 |
| 2018-01-19T04:00:02 | 5 | 131,094 | 9744125,266 | 12427264 | 48411931,21 | 61108754 |
| 2018-01-19T05:00:02 | 6 | 32,095 | 9611176,162 | 12369920 | 48495481,2 | 60948515 |
| 2018-01-19T06:00:02 | 6 | 183,844 | 9812070,916 | 12345344 | 48717604,98 | 61525556 |
| 2018-01-19T07:00:02 | 6 | 35,492 | 9622592,805 | 12345344 | 48667074,86 | 61624355 |
| 2018-01-19T08:00:02 | 4 | 95,824 | 9754413,18 | 12509184 | 48829982,69 | 61603875 |
| 2018-01-19T09:00:02 | 4 | 314,905 | 9532744,351 | 12509184 | 48097223,55 | 60692515 |
| 2018-01-19T10:00:02 | 4 | 271,334 | 9716421,388 | 12427264 | 47736555,72 | 60361234 |
| 2018-01-19T11:00:02 | 4 | 46,671 | 9645834,387 | 12460032 | 48561369,07 | 61299713 |
| 2018-01-19T12:00:02 | 4 | 72,906 | 9688054,024 | 12509184 | 48725634,14 | 61720116 |
| 2018-01-19T13:00:03 | 4 | 89,382 | 9721907,268 | 12386304 | 48358407,64 | 61247935 |
| 2018-01-19T14:00:03 | 4 | 34,53 | 9775841,13 | 12419072 | 48939781,7 | 61718975 |
| 2018-01-19T15:00:02 | 7 | 37,369 | 9627499,878 | 12312576 | 48990150,91 | 61643694 |
| 2018-01-19T16:00:02 | 6 | 251,355 | 9838841,628 | 12451840 | 48369089,15 | 60788276 |
| 2018-01-19T17:00:02 | 4 | 113,982 | 9733041,185 | 12402688 | 48625526,77 | 61371956 |
| 2018-01-19T18:00:02 | 4 | 83,473 | 9734033,97 | 12460032 | 47808274,64 | 60334115 |
| 2018-01-19T19:00:03 | 4 | 34,271 | 9589739,453 | 12386304 | 48724229,22 | 61603875 |
| 2018-01-19T20:00:02 | 4 | 222,44 | 9260891,721 | 11845632 | 48120715,56 | 60507054 |
| 2018-01-19T21:00:02 | 4 | 145,296 | 9682721,04 | 12337152 | 48854437,44 | 61411775 |
| 2018-01-19T22:00:02 | 4 | 361,843 | 9820471,907 | 12435456 | 43138745,36 | 54387713 |
| 2018-01-19T23:00:02 | 4 | 46,525 | 9635708,711 | 12402688 | 48798356,31 | 61562915 |
| 2018-01-20T00:00:03 | 4 | 34,452 | 9668489,844 | 12484608 | 48757971,66 | 61310516 |
| 2018-01-20T01:00:02 | 3 | 278,132 | 9689869,09 | 12222464 | 46157167,11 | 58060835 |
| 2018-01-20T02:00:02 | 3 | 34,061 | 9792897,952 | 12402688 | 48932899,98 | 61712914 |
| 2018-01-20T03:00:02 | 3 | 222,601 | 9575894,45 | 12083200 | 47324165 | 59702836 |
| 2018-01-20T04:00:02 | 3 | 166,744 | 9744894,948 | 12361728 | 48328298,24 | 60944914 |
| 2018-01-20T05:00:02 | 3 | 34,551 | 9390160,981 | 12288000 | 48892598,24 | 61720116 |
| 2018-01-20T06:00:02 | 3 | 46,744 | 9672963,671 | 12328960 | 37214289,67 | 47404033 |
| 2018-01-20T07:00:03 | 4 | 35,149 | 9412055,695 | 12353536 | 48837220,36 | 61706275 |
| 2018-01-20T08:00:02 | 4 | 167,273 | 9916437,273 | 12509184 | 48624106,32 | 61491235 |
| 2018-01-20T09:00:02 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2018-01-20T10:00:02 | 4 | 34,626 | 9821330,998 | 12509184 | 49087689,85 | 61698495 |
| 2018-01-20T11:00:02 | 4 | 35,57 | 9840213,05 | 12476416 | 48982928,05 | 61630994 |
| 2018-01-20T12:00:03 | 4 | 39,17 | 9711952,767 | 12378112 | 47536559,25 | 59759534 |
| 2018-01-20T13:00:02 | 4 | 34,849 | 9768321,062 | 12451840 | 48665417,09 | 61597236 |
| 2018-01-20T14:00:02 | 4 | 261,139 | 9852836,972 | 12476416 | 48125700,89 | 60684735 |
| 2018-01-20T15:00:02 | 4 | 233,061 | 9857791,641 | 12443648 | 48855680,99 | 61668353 |
| 2018-01-20T16:00:02 | 4 | 287,165 | 9559165,811 | 12222464 | 43314049,88 | 54497315 |
| 2018-01-20T17:00:03 | 4 | 186,966 | 9593515,219 | 12148736 | 47097072,51 | 59261375 |
| 2018-01-20T18:00:02 | 4 | 224,053 | 9691654,467 | 12468224 | 46005853,6 | 57842194 |
| 2018-01-20T19:00:02 | 4 | 31,884 | 9462821,554 | 12460032 | 48638421,97 | 61597236 |
| 2018-01-20T20:00:03 | 4 | 377,088 | 9707508,733 | 12419072 | 42028705,03 | 53026356 |
| 2018-01-20T21:00:02 | 4 | 71,191 | 9594447,372 | 12271616 | 48585457,4 | 61293074 |
| 2018-01-20T22:00:03 | 4 | 402,03 | 9766419,252 | 12410880 | 43656862,13 | 55026194 |
| 2018-01-20T23:00:02 | 4 | 126,011 | 9820064,279 | 12476416 | 48456382,81 | 61098514 |
| 2018-01-21T00:00:02 | 4 | 30,814 | 9694778,042 | 12476416 | 48751062,66 | 61696035 |
| 2018-01-21T01:00:02 | 3 | 122,291 | 9628735,163 | 12353536 | 49024854,65 | 61679156 |
| 2018-01-21T02:00:02 | 3 | 30,904 | 9766703,252 | 12492800 | 48218443,23 | 60829236 |
| 2018-01-21T03:00:02 | 3 | 30,8 | 9649319,683 | 12296192 | 47199545,82 | 59504675 |
| 2018-01-21T04:00:03 | 3 | 150,728 | 9732168,545 | 12468224 | 49028891,8 | 61699636 |
| 2018-01-21T05:00:02 | 3 | 171,024 | 9770520,848 | 12451840 | 48830477,7 | 61644835 |
| 2018-01-21T06:00:03 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2018-01-21T07:00:02 | 4 | 38,696 | 9741383,448 | 12460032 | 48820723,98 | 61596095 |
| 2018-01-21T08:00:03 | 4 | 115,45 | 9787380,211 | 12394496 | 48989508,54 | 61630994 |
| 2018-01-21T09:00:02 | 4 | 31,272 | 8824419,77 | 12427264 | 49003295,18 | 61720116 |
| 2018-01-21T10:00:02 | 4 | 110,753 | 9546247,819 | 12402688 | 49002122,52 | 61600274 |
| 2018-01-21T11:00:02 | 4 | 62,478 | 9663107,904 | 12156928 | 48720372,19 | 61425616 |
| 2018-01-21T12:00:02 | 4 | 157,061 | 9858328,414 | 12476416 | 47341355,93 | 59781155 |
| 2018-01-21T13:00:02 | 4 | 298,394 | 9847295,114 | 12468224 | 47031074,18 | 59514915 |
| 2018-01-21T14:00:02 | 4 | 38,377 | 9637879,703 | 12328960 | 48113751,78 | 60504594 |
| 2018-01-21T15:00:03 | 4 | 357,521 | 9889451,173 | 12451840 | 48899863,95 | 61542435 |
| 2018-01-21T16:00:03 | 4 | 415,393 | 9649956,506 | 12386304 | 42713104,44 | 54135314 |
| 2018-01-21T17:00:02 | 4 | 106,568 | 9849859,289 | 12468224 | 48925673,03 | 61668916 |
| 2018-01-21T18:00:03 | 4 | 54,189 | 9700058,593 | 12492800 | 46432185,7 | 58360255 |
| 2018-01-21T19:00:02 | 4 | 54,223 | 9755228,651 | 12394496 | 48463559,72 | 61371956 |
| 2018-01-21T20:00:02 | 4 | 189,218 | 9705393,618 | 12410880 | 46319602,94 | 58251794 |
| 2018-01-21T21:00:02 | 4 | 46,637 | 9749068,717 | 12468224 | 48916354,93 | 61674414 |
| 2018-01-21T22:00:02 | 6 | 145,501 | 9745608,012 | 12345344 | 44254102,77 | 55851455 |
| 2018-01-21T23:00:02 | 4 | 141,066 | 9836329,878 | 12460032 | 41675563,36 | 52561955 |
| 2018-01-22T00:00:02 | 6 | 255,927 | 9731630,583 | 12484608 | 44996688,54 | 56681473 |
| 2018-01-22T01:00:02 | 5 | 34,757 | 9724611,372 | 12484608 | 48804046,28 | 61573155 |
| 2018-01-22T02:00:02 | 5 | 119,807 | 9552364,774 | 12214272 | 46876410,53 | 59395636 |
| 2018-01-22T03:00:02 | 5 | 35,74 | 9645858,424 | 12451840 | 48595139,42 | 61337635 |
| 2018-01-22T04:00:03 | 5 | 34,357 | 9768391,86 | 12451840 | 48506360,43 | 61290036 |
| 2018-01-22T05:00:02 | 4 | 118,107 | 9709315,767 | 12378112 | 48636212,49 | 61575615 |
| 2018-01-22T06:00:02 | 5 | 88,998 | 9674934,44 | 12369920 | 48928524,55 | 61689396 |
| 2018-01-22T07:00:02 | 6 | 203,9 | 9567271,18 | 12271616 | 46796952,93 | 59002915 |
| 2018-01-22T08:00:03 | 6 | 152,93 | 9705874,575 | 12328960 | 38637205,41 | 48923154 |
| 2018-01-22T09:00:02 | 4 | 397,185 | 9756511,807 | 12435456 | 48207609,63 | 60682275 |
| 2018-01-22T10:00:02 | 5 | 37,635 | 9721322,218 | 12451840 | 49083999,72 | 61694894 |
| 2018-01-22T11:00:02 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2018-01-22T12:00:02 | 6 | 232,739 | 9697884,915 | 12402688 | 46989084,48 | 59428816 |
| 2018-01-22T13:00:02 | 5 | 36,268 | 9801424,5 | 12427264 | 49079600,06 | 61743634 |
| 2018-01-22T14:00:02 | 6 | 188,08 | 9762041,783 | 12435456 | 45773043,49 | 57780754 |
| 2018-01-22T15:00:02 | 5 | 34,873 | 9746529,95 | 12468224 | 48753134,63 | 61689396 |
| 2018-01-22T16:00:02 | 5 | 353,239 | 9810805,36 | 12468224 | 46946387,42 | 59463715 |
| 2018-01-22T17:00:02 | 4 | 97,762 | 9724076,93 | 12435456 | 46884642,72 | 59449874 |
| 2018-01-22T18:00:02 | 4 | 181,057 | 9733598,532 | 12279808 | 47584270,96 | 59824575 |
| 2018-01-22T19:00:02 | 5 | 148,215 | 9754228,767 | 12476416 | 47308584,13 | 59644434 |
| 2018-01-22T20:00:02 | 5 | 34,63 | 9706193,739 | 12247040 | 40835207,01 | 51350034 |
| 2018-01-22T21:00:02 | 7 | 88,201 | 9725487,351 | 12386304 | 47645916,9 | 60070335 |
| 2018-01-22T22:00:02 | 6 | 84,979 | 9528844,746 | 12214272 | 44049695,98 | 55544833 |
| 2018-01-22T23:00:02 | 5 | 34,386 | 9859645,724 | 12443648 | 48405971,99 | 60839476 |
```

*(Source: Raspberry Pi 3 in Munich to Vodafone speedtest server in Frankfurt.)*

Comment: My previous answer may have been wrong. Can you advise what the upload, download and ping cold mean?  (The pi may be able to handle >50megabits, and if the upload cool is the upload speed in bytes, it's all over the place indicating the problem is not the pi).  Ideally you would disconnect everything else from your LAN, run MTR as well (to check path, packet loss and latency variance)

Answer (score 0):

Your slow connection is most likely a result of using bad routing hardware, not by the isp. The problem is not the 100MBit Port, but since this is old technology he might have thought the processor of your routing hardware might be too slow to even do the basic routing tasks. 
To test it you can connect a pc directly to the fiber hardware and see if your problem persists, this is a solution every isp suggests first, and you should try that before digging for something else. Those guys, especially if it's fiber, can test your connection very accurate.

Comment: How do I "test" if my infrastructure is enough? As I want to test consistently I need a cheap PC maybe my NAS can handle the task?

Comment: A NAS could work, but it has to have access to a resource that has consistent bandwidth, otherwise the problems could also be caused by the server you connect to. Most reliable information is what the isp can give you, since he can test from the nearest login server directly to your modem.

Comment: It would be directly linked to my router (provided by the ISP). The ISP itself says everything is ok. As I mentioned in the background, I still "feel" problems in the evening as performance is really slow.

Comment: What you "feel" can also be caused by the website you are browsing being frequented too much. You'd have to have a reliable server that has 100% uptime, killer bandwidth and no usage at all to be sure.